# Squid in docker returns 502 but works when run on host

Tags: docker, proxy, squid, socket.io

I'm using the same config for squid 5.6 that runs on a host machine and in docker. When I run it on the host (Ubuntu 22.10) it works just fine but when I run it from `ubuntu/squid` image I get 502 bad gateway error.

Squid config:

```
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
#http_access deny !Safe_ports
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
http_access allow localhost
#http_access deny all
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
http_upgrade_request_protocols OTHER allow all

debug_options ALL,1 11,3 31,3 65,3
```

This is how I run it via docker:

```
docker run -v /etc/squid/squid.conf:/etc/squid/squid.conf -p 3128:3128 ubuntu/squid
```

Logs when running squid on the host machine (works fine):

```
2022/11/23 13:13:56.878 kid1| 11,2| client_side.cc(1357) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client conn7 local=x.x.x.x:3128 remote=y.y.y.y:56636 FD 11 flags=1
2022/11/23 13:13:56.891 kid1| 11,2| client_side.cc(1358) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client REQUEST:
---------
GET https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIadwKA&b64=1 HTTP/1.1
user-agent: node-XMLHttpRequest
accept: */*
Host: example.com:443
connection: close


----------
2022/11/23 13:13:57.233 kid1| 11,3| http.cc(2498) httpStart: GET https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIadwKA&b64=1
2022/11/23 13:13:57.234 kid1| 11,2| http.cc(2454) sendRequest: HTTP Server conn10 local=x.x.x.x:47078 remote=z.z.z.z:443 HIER_DIRECT FD 13 flags=1
2022/11/23 13:13:57.234 kid1| 11,2| http.cc(2455) sendRequest: HTTP Server REQUEST:
---------
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIadwKA&b64=1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: node-XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
Via: 1.1 squid-new (squid/5.6)
X-Forwarded-For: y.y.y.y
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive


----------
2022/11/23 13:13:57.390 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: 'https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIadwKA&b64=1'
2022/11/23 13:13:57.390 kid1| 11,3| http.cc(666) processReplyHeader: processReplyHeader: key '0100000000000000FFB9000001000000'
2022/11/23 13:13:57.390 kid1| 11,2| http.cc(720) processReplyHeader: HTTP Server conn10 local=x.x.x.x:47078 remote=z.z.z.z:443 HIER_DIRECT FD 13 flags=1
2022/11/23 13:13:57.391 kid1| 11,2| http.cc(721) processReplyHeader: HTTP Server RESPONSE:
---------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 13:13:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 100
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: io=TXpnzoBUkck9fUgiAAGO; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
```

Logs when I run it in docker (502 gateway):

```
1669209346.964    475 y.y.y.y TCP_MISS/502 4012 GET https://example.com/socket.io/? - HIER_DIRECT/z.z.z.z text/html
2022/11/23 13:15:46.488| 11,2| client_side.cc(1357) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client conn6 local=172.17.0.2:31288 remote=y.y.y.y:56834 FD 10 flags=1
2022/11/23 13:15:46.488| 11,2| client_side.cc(1358) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client REQUEST:
---------
GET https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIaeL57&b64=1 HTTP/1.1
user-agent: node-XMLHttpRequest
accept: */*
Host: example.com:443
connection: close


----------
2022/11/23 13:15:46.809| 11,3| http.cc(2498) httpStart: GET https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIaeL57&b64=1
2022/11/23 13:15:46.810| 11,2| http.cc(2454) sendRequest: HTTP Server conn9 local=172.17.0.2:45890 remote=z.z.z.z:443 HIER_DIRECT FD 12 flags=1
2022/11/23 13:15:46.810| 11,2| http.cc(2455) sendRequest: HTTP Server REQUEST:
---------
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OIaeL57&b64=1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: node-XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
Via: 1.1 d6850669e571 (squid/5.6)
X-Forwarded-For: y.y.y.y
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive


----------
2022/11/23 13:15:46.963| 11,2| http.cc(1291) readReply: conn9 local=172.17.0.2:45890 remote=z.z.z.z:443 HIER_DIRECT FD 12 flags=1: read failure: (0) No error.
2022/11/23 13:15:46.963| 11,2| Stream.cc(279) sendStartOfMessage: HTTP Client conn6 local=172.17.0.2:31288 remote=y.y.y.y:56834 FD 10 flags=1
2022/11/23 13:15:46.963| 11,2| Stream.cc(280) sendStartOfMessage: HTTP Client REPLY:
---------
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: squid/5.6
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 13:15:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3637
X-Squid-Error: ERR_READ_ERROR 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from d6850669e571
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from d6850669e571:31288
Via: 1.1 d6850669e571 (squid/5.6)
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the problem with ubuntu/squid image not docker in general. The image is currently marked as beta or edge, not stable. I built a alpine-based squid image and it has resolved my issue.